# iOS layer color change

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

For my custom UIView I've overriden `touchesBegan` method. What I told it to do is to change its' layer's background color:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
    self.layer.backgroundColor = clr_someCGColor
}
```

It acts weird. If I quickly tap the view while in Landscape it does everything perfectly well, but if I do this in Portrait, I have to hold it for some time to see the result, however the `touchesEnded` method is called right away, if I quickly tap. What could be the reason, causing the delay in Portrait?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `dispatch_async` wrapper. All it does is cause a delay (we can't execute on the main thread until, as you rightly say, the tap ends and `touchesEnded` has come and gone). You are *already* on the main thread, in `touchesBegan`, so there is no need for this extra delay.

Even better, use a tap gesture recognizer.

Comment: I put it in `dispatch_async` wrapper after I first experienced the problem and removing it again did not help. `UITapGestureRecognizer` does not give the full control over touch events, which I need to set the layer's bg to `clr_active` and then back to `clr_normal`, after touches end

Comment: That's fine. But the `dispatch_async` is not helping you here. I have an app where I do this same sort of thing: I have a tap gesture recognizer, but I also want to switch between active look and inactive look while the finger is down, so I use `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded`, and it works fine. The problem can be in code you have not shown — but you have not shown it, so there is now way to know.